# Result from a multiprocessing loop

Tags: python, loops, multiprocessing

I'm running the following program, in order to compare different times between multiprocessing and single core processing.

Here is the script :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from time import *

#Amount to calculate
N=5000

#Fonction that works alone
def two_loops(x):
    t=0
    for i in range(1,x+1):
       for j in range(i):
           t+=1
    return t

#Function that need to be called in a loop
def single_loop(x):
    tt=0
    for j in range(x):
        tt+=1
    return tt

print 'Starting loop function'
starttime=time()
tot=0
for i in range(1,N+1):
    tot+=single_loop(i)
print 'Single loop function. Result ',tot,' in ', time()-starttime,' seconds'


print 'Starting multiprocessing function'
if __name__=='__main__':
    starttime=time()

    pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    res= pool.map(single_loop,range(1,N+1))
    pool.close()
    print 'MP function. Result ',res,' in ', time()-starttime,' seconds'


print 'Starting two loops function'
starttime=time()
print 'Two loops onction. Result ',two_loops(N),' in ', time()-starttime,' seconds'
```

So basically the functions gives me the sum of all integers between 1 and N (so N(N+1)/2). 
The **two_loops** function is the basic one, using two *for* loops. The **single_loop** is just created to simulate one loop (the j loop).

When I'm running this script, this works well but I don't get the right result. I get :

> Starting loop function Single loop function. Result  12502500  in 
>   0.380275964737  seconds
>
> Starting multiprocessing function MP function. Result  [1, 2, 3,... *a
>   lot of values here* ...,4999, 5000]  in  0.683819055557  seconds
>
> Starting two loops function Two loops onction. Result  12502500  in 
>   0.4114818573  seconds

It looks like the script runs, but I can't manage to get the good result. I saw on a the web that the close() function was supposed to do that, but apparently not.

Do you know how I can do ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Where is boucle defined?

Comment: Please don't use python 2: https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: You should put all your mainline (first column) code so it is protected by `if __name__=='__main__'`

Comment: @Marc Sorry I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question but here's how it can be done:

```
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor
from timeit import Timer


def two_loops_multiprocessing():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(single_loop, range(N))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    iterations, elapsed_time = Timer("two_loops(N)", globals=globals()).autorange()
    print(elapsed_time / iterations)

    iterations, elapsed_time = Timer("two_loops_multiprocessing()", globals=globals()).autorange()
    print(elapsed_time / iterations)
```

Comment: Can explain your code ? I’m confused with the « iterations, elapsed_time » variables you made.

My question was simply to make my multiprocessing method to give me the good result, which it doesn’t by giving me a list of numbers

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Well, as I said it's supposed to be 12502500  in this precise case (N=5000). As you can see, it works for the two basics functions, but the multiprocessing only gives me a list, which is absolutely not what I'm wanting

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your map function is chopping up your range you provide it and runs the single loop function for all these separate numbers. Look here to see what it does: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map And since your single loop just adds 1 to tt for a range up to the value you get the value back. This effectively means you get your range() object back which is the answer you get.

In your other "single loop"  you later add all the values you get together to get to a single value here:

```
for i in range(1,N+1):
    tot+=single_loop(i)
```

But you forget to do this with you multiprocessing. What you should do is add a loop after you have called your map function to add them all together and you will get your expected answer.

Besides this your single loop function is basically a two loop function where you moved one loop to a function call. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but there is not a big difference between the two.

Comment: My goal is to try to make the program run faster by using all available cores. Sure the single_loop and two_loops functions are almost the same, but I'm separating the two loops in order to make one run in multiprocessing. I thought that you can only replace one loop by the multiprocessing command, since the inner loop (the one inside the single_loop function) depends of the first one. So, basically, when you say I have to add a loop to sum all the map() results, it adds processing time so I don't see the point of using multiprocessing then.

Comment: If this is all you are trying to accomplish then no, multiprocessing is not something you want to be doing, if you have more calculation intensive things you need to do then it can be very helpful to use multiprocessing. If what you do in the single loop for example would take several seconds per call then it would possibly speed up your function considerably.

Comment: Of course, this is just a test to try multiprocessing. 
I plan to use it for way more complex scripts

Comment: But you know what to do now right? Your program was working except there was one thing that you needed to add and then it works as you planned.

Comment: Well sort of. I don't know if using the sum() function (or a for loop) is just going to add much calculus time, isn't it ? I mean, if my goal is to reduce the process time by making the loops run in parallel, then adding a function at the end might waste the effort right ?

Comment: When you say you are going to use it for way more complex scripts it will decrease your computation time considerably. In such a case the effort is not wasted. In this simple example you could argue it is.

Comment: So I tried this script using 96 cores, and for N=50000, the two functions take about 38 seconds while the pool() takes approximately 1.6 seconds. This is awesome !

Answer (score 0):

Just sum the result list:

```
res = sum(pool.map(single_loop,range(1,N+1)))
```

You could avoid calculating the sum in the main thread by using some shared memory, but keep in mind that you will lose more time on synchronization. And again, there's no gain from multiprocessing in this case. It all depends on the specific case. If you needed to call single_loop fewer times and each call would take more time, then multiprocessing would speed up your code.